# Strange problem with ViewFlipper

Tags: android, viewflipper

I have a ViewFlipper that shows 2 imageview (red one when disconnected and the green other when connected), however, i have a strange result: sometimes the red image is showen when i'm connected, it switches like this : red-green-and returns red(even when i'm connected).
Here is the JAVA code:

```
public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {

                        updateStatus("Enregistré au serveur.");
                        Log.d("SUCCEED","Registration DONE");

                        final ViewFlipper flipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.flipper);
                        flipper.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                        flipper.showNext();
                            }
                        },2000);}
```

The view is initiated with the red image, then, when connected(and after 2 seconds) the next image is normally showen.

What could be the problem?
Thank you very much.

EDIT: XML file (Handler)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/sipLabel"
  android:textSize="20sp"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />
  <ImageView android:id="@+id/status"  android:layout_below="@id/sipLabel" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="0.35" android:gravity="center"

         />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: @Zelimir: no, i didn't solved this issue! I installed the apk in my phone and it always returns to the red image. Any idea please ? Thank you.

Comment: @Zelimir: Any idea please ? Can i use other thing than the viewflipper ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do that differently. If that is just a matter of displaying different image (red/green) I would use ImageView UI control to display that image. And for the delayed display update you may use Handler. Something like this:

```
public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) 
{
    updateStatus("Enregistré au serveur.");
    Log.d("SUCCEED","Registration DONE");

    mRegistered = true;
    mRegistrationUpdateHandler.removeCallbacks(handleUpdateStatus);
    mRegistrationUpdateHandler.postDelayed(handleUpdateStatus, 2000);
}

public void onRegistrationLost()
{
    mRegistered = false;
    mRegistrationUpdateHandler.removeCallbacks(handleUpdateStatus);
    mRegistrationUpdateHandler.postDelayed(handleUpdateStatus, 2000);
}

private Runnable handleUpdateStatus = new Runnable() 
{     
    public void run()
    {
        ImageView statusImageDisplay = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.statusImage);
        if (mRegistered)
        {
            statusImageDisplay.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imageGreen));
        else
        {
            statusImageDisplay.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imageRed));
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: @Zelimir: Sorry for disturbing you, but i have a small question: what is the parameter of "setImageBitmap" ? I put a drawable but have an error and i'm not finding some useful links. And the XML file soes it contain one image or the 2 ones ? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Zelimir: I did this is that correct ? Bitmap bMapCon = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("R.drawable.connected"); Plus i set all the variables(mRegistered and the Handler) as global variables. The XML file has one image that it changes in function of the status(the handler changes it). Right ?

Comment: @Zelimir: there is no image showen in the UI. Sureley because of this line:Bitmap bMapCon = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("R.drawable.connected"); However, how to solve it ?? Thank you.

Comment: @androniennn - Updated my answer. Sorry, I should use originally setImageDrawable(), and in your Drawables you should have imageRed.png and imageGreen.png.

Comment: @Zelimir: thank you for your answer, and i did exactly but you writed to me but i have not an image showen. The 2 images are well present in Drawables with .png extension. What could be the problem ?

Comment: @androiennn - Firstly please verify that handleUpdateStatus is triggered by the Handler, so that image change is requested.

Comment: @Zelimir: i debug this line(statusImageDisplay.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imageGreen));) and i'm not finding a clear output information. don't know how to verify if handleUpdateStatus is triggered by the Handler. How doing it please ?

Comment: @androiennn - Just put some LogCat trace and Log.i() into several places in the handleUpdateStatus and see what happens when you register/unregister.

Comment: @Zelimir: I put some log BUT i'm not seeing them in logcat! i put them in the handleUpdateStatus function and when wanting to set the image when registered. Never has such problem :\

Comment: Maybe it is because handler was not correctly triggered. Be sure that you put removeCallbacks() before postDelayed(). Can you verify that postDelayed() line was reached?

Comment: @Zelimir: i notice that the compiler doesn't read/execute this lines. Why? Strange problem :\

Comment: @androiennn - But you could verify that onRegistrationDone() is called, and handler triggering is just there.

Comment: @Zelimir: yes, onRegistrationDone() is well called and all the instructions in this function is executed but not the lines that changes the image. could it a variable problem(i set them as global[ the boolean one and the handler]) ?

Comment: @androiennn - Global variables, you mean members of that Activity class, so they are visible throughout the whole Activity. It is ok to set those two as members, but have you done mRegistrationUpdateHandler = new Handler(); in the Activity onCreate()?

Comment: @androiennn - one more thing. Please check how often registrationDone() and registrationLost() occur. Because if they are due to some issue toggled with period shorter than 2 seconds you will not get Handler called (in fact runnable vill be removed before it was executed).

Comment: @Zelimir: i checked how many times the function onregistrationdone() is called and i see in the log it's called 2 times. I increased the time to 8 seconds and always don't have an image(red or green) showen. Could not be an XML problem(i posted it in my first post) ?

Comment: @Zelimir: I really searched for the cause of the problem and i'm not finding the source of it. I think that i'll stick with viewflipper(it's bugged but at least it shows the images :\). And please if you have any idea, or if you want me to post the code excerpt, notice me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @androiennn - OK, It's a pity that it was not successful, we invested a lot of effort. Regards.